# Meteor.method arguments used in Mongo call

Tags: meteor

I want to write this call as a Method: `Posts.update(this._id, { $set: { status: 'accepted' }})`

```
Meteor.methods({
    ...
    updatePost: function(id, key, value) {
        Posts.update(id, { $set: { key: value }});
}
})
```

`Meteor.call('updatePost', this._id, 'status', 'accepted')` does not work. I'm guessing because of the `'status'`? How could I get this to work? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it isn't working because you can't use variable names as keys in JavaScript object literals. You'll need to use bracket notation instead. Give this a try:

```js
Meteor.methods({
  updatePost: function(id, key, value) {
    check(id, String);
    check(key, String);
    check(value, String);

    var obj = {};
    obj[key] = value;
    return Posts.update(id, {$set: obj});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables can't be defined as keys in javascript. Something like this could do it though:

```
var update = {};
update[key] = value;
Posts.update(id, { $set: update });
```